# Do UI views have default gesture recognizers attached?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` class that's also a gesture delegate:

```
@interface MyCell: UITableViewCell<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

I want to use it with my own gesture recognizer. But it also gets called by some `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` instance. I don't know where it comes from, and I most certainly did not instantiate more gesture recognizers in my code.

Who instantiates it, and how I turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are default gesture recognizers. You can enumerate the existing gesture recognizers with the `gestureRecognizers` property on any `UIView`. The `enabled` property allows you to turn off any gesture recognizer.

According to the documentation, the preferred method for disabling a gesture recognizer is to return `NO` for `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` or `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` which will prevent the gesture recognizer from acting without altering its state.

You may find this documentation helpful: [Event Handling Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html).

Comment: It is a really bad idea to disable gesture recognizers that you don't control.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote. The answer was factually correct and answered the question. I have edited to clarify following the Apple documentation.

Comment: The downvote is because prior to your edit, you seemed to have suggested disabling gesture recognizers that you don't control, which is, again, a really bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20065004/1. Since you have updated your comment, I removed the downvote.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not entirely clear what *default* recognisers are installed by various `UIView`s, and the docs don't mention it. I also examined `gestureRecognizers` of each cell superview up to the top, some views have system recognizers (nostly to do with scrolling and nav gestures), but none of them are `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: @zadr why is it bad to disable default gesture recognisers? Do you have a doc reference?

Comment: @AlexB It's not public. There's no API documenting that it's okay to do. Don't touch it.